# Handler Mapping For Classic Asp .asp extension pages giving errors at IIS Integrated Pipe Line Mode

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I am trying to run classic Asp pages in the IIS 7 **Integrated** pipe line mode. Thus, I have added following Handler mapping into Web.Config.

```
add name="ASPClassic" 
path="*.asp" 
verb="GET,HEAD,POST" 
modules="IsapiModule" 
scriptProcessor="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" 
requireAccess="Script"
resourceType="Unspecified"
```

But, when .asp pages are being requested, **Server Application Unavailable** error is raised and the detailed application event log said that:

A request mapped to aspnet_isapi.dll was made within an application pool running in Integrated .NET mode.  Aspnet_isapi.dll can only be used when running in Classic .NET mode.  Please either specify preCondition="ISAPImode" on the handler mapping to make it run only in application pools running in Classic .NET mode, or move the application to another application pool running in Classic .NET mode in order to use this handler mapping.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 10):

The script processor for Classic ASP is not:

> `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll`

but:

> `%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll`

Here's the correct handler mapping entry from IIS7's `applicationHost.config` file when Classic ASP is installed:

```
<add name="ASPClassic" 
     path="*.asp" 
     verb="GET,HEAD,POST" 
     modules="IsapiModule" 
     scriptProcessor="%windir%\system32\inetsrv\asp.dll" 
     resourceType="File" />
```

It sounds like you've not installed Classic ASP on your server or workstation.

On Windows 7 you need to go to *Control Panel -> Programs and Features* then click "Turn Windows features on or off". You'll get a window that looks like this, make sure "ASP" is ticked:

[image]

On Windows 2008R2 go to *Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Server Manager*. Click on "Roles" in the left hand panel then scroll down to "Web Server (IIS)". There should be a list of "Role Services" like this (I've highlighted ASP which is installed on the server I took this screen shot from):

[image]

If ASP is not installed then click on "Add Role Services" and tick the ASP checkbox under *Web Server -> Application Development* and click Next to complete the installation.

If all is well then you should see the Handler Mapping in IIS Manager:

[image]

Comment: Really appreciate your contribution. I will check this out and mark your answer accepted as soon as possible.

Comment: I found this while troubleshooting a different problem, and found that I don't have ASP classic installed, and yet **ASP scripts work fine on my machine**.  How is this possible?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank - What OS are you running?

Comment: @Kev: Windows 8 with IIS 8.0

Comment: @Kev: Home, I think, 64 bit processor.

Comment: @JoshuaFrank - Control Panel -> System will tell you

Comment: @Kev: I looked there, and it didn't say Home, but it didn't say Pro either, so I think it's Home.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that in order to run classic asp pages in IIS 7 you still need to install that?
(It is not  Installed by Default on IIS 7.)

See here how to add the asp module depending on wether this your on windows7 or windows server 2008 : http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/asp

*Btw: what you are trying to do is indeed script mapping in classic pipeline mode.* 

See also : http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/building-and-running-aspnet-applications/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-integrated-pipeline_