# This type of page is not served

Tags: asp.net

> Server Error in '/_' Application. This type of page is not served.
>   Description: The type of page you have requested is not served because
>   it has been explicitly forbidden.  The extension '.asp' may be
>   incorrect.   Please review the URL below and make sure that it is
>   spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /_/filename.asp
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.5466;
>   ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.5456

Comment: add .asp verb in IIS. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15356441/handler-mapping-for-classic-asp-asp-extension-pages-giving-errors-at-iis-integr

Comment: *Don't* add the `asp` server in IIS. In fact, don't use ASP at all.  ASP is the technology used before .NET came out in 2003. ASP.NET pages have an `aspx` extension.

Answer (score 0):

I think you saved the file with wrong extension, Save the file as '.aspx' instead of '.asp'

Comment: Yup.. it is asp file .. means I didn't save in wrong extension.. old version asp file.